# How can I make Chrome respect "scroll-snap-stop: always"?

Tags: html, css

I have a page using that uses full-screen CSS scroll snapping. Below is a minimal reproduction of the page:

```css
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;

  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
```

```html
<section style="background-color: red;"></section>
<section style="background-color: blue;"></section>
<section style="background-color: green;"></section>
```

In Firefox (version 85), this gives me the desired behavior: smooth scrolling that stops at every point, regardless of *how* I scroll (mouse scroll wheel, touchscreen, touchpad). However, when I scroll through the same page in Chrome (version 88), a single click of my mouse's scroll wheel rapidly jumps to the bottom. I would expect `scroll-snap-stop: always` to fix this, but it still occurs. Does anyone know how I can make full-screen scroll snapping work consistently between both browsers?

Comment: It's working for me

Comment: Not working for me in Version 115.0.5790.170.